# How to print both Key and value pair in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

Can anyone have the idea to print both key and value value in jenkins?

Ex: I am using Extended choice parameter with a property file defined. My properties file have below entries.

India=Mumbai, chennai, Delhi
US=Chicago,LV

I want to print both Delhi and India, if user select Delhi while triggering the build.

Comment: Below is the solution:

1.Read the property from the properties file, which is used in Extended choice parameter
2.Set the Global environment variables for INDIA and US
3.use the "Execute shell script" to print the value
       eval echo \$$<Your_choice>

It will print either India or US depending on your choice

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the steps? I am also trying to print both key value  values in jenkins, but somehow not able to get the correct result